# How can I get data using if else in laravel elequent

Tags: sql, database, laravel

Suppose I have a Salary model contains column of month and year 
I want to fetch data like

```
    Salary::where((year==date('Y') && month<date('m')) || year<date('Y'))->get()
```

How can I get in laravel elequent?

Comment: use group `where()` clause

Comment: @Sohel0415 would you give an example please?

Comment: Do you have a `month` and `year` column in your table or just `date` column??

Comment: @RossWilson Salary model contains column of month and year

Comment: I got a solution like SetEmployeeSalary::where([['year','=',date('Y')],['month','<',date('m')]])
                                ->orWhere('year','<',date('Y'))
                                ->get(); is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Salary::where([
        ['year', '=', date('Y')],
        ['month', '<', date('m')]
    ])
    ->orWhere('year', '<', date('Y'))
    ->get()
```